# Computing $a ^ {^nC_r}$ % prime

Tags: algorithm, math, modular-arithmetic

[image: Question]

I have uploaded my problem as screenshot.

Comment: MathJax is not operational on this site. Could you re-do your expressions to be more understandable here? You could use graphics--if you do not have enough reputation to put them directly into your question, link to them and others can edit them in.

Comment: Your theorem is wrong. Consider (7^9)%5. The answer is 2. However (7^(9%5))%5 = (7^4)%5 = 1. You might want to take this to https://math.stackexchange.com to ask if there is a way of simplifying the maths you want to do. I'm guessing you at least know that (a^b)%m = ((a%m)^b)%m ?

Comment: Check out [Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem)

Comment: @Chris yes i know it. I guess its computational, and that maths can't help me reduce it further.

Comment: @user58697 hey i know Lucas Theorem. but problem here is exponent can be computed only with modulo.

Comment: How large is M in general? If its not too big you might be able to find k such that `a^k = 1 mod M` and then you could use that `a^b = a^c mod M` where c = b mod k (I am pretty sure that is right).

Comment: @Chris M=10^9+7. It looks like something i need. Can you give more insight to how you got there? And ofcourse, we can use k=M-1 using Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Fermat's little theorem says

```
x^p mod p = x mod p     or     x^(p-1) mod p = 1  (if p does not divide x)
```

We can use this to reduce the number of operations for computing `x^m` (`m` arbitrary) when `p` doesn't divide `x`:

1. Divide `m` by `(p-1)` and get: `s = (m mod p-1)`; no need to compute the quotient
2. Note that `m = (p-1)q + s` and `x^(p-1) = 1 mod p`. So,

   - `x^m = x^((p-1)q)x^s = (1^q)(x^s) mod p = x^(m mod p-1)`

The problem that remains, however, is how to compute

```
choose(n,r) = n(n-1)...(n-r+1)/(r(r-1)...1) mod p-1
```

**Addendum**

Further thinking on the problem above leads us to consider the following. We have three integers:

```
c = choose(n,r)
m = n(n-1)...(n-r+1)
f = factorial(r)
q = p-1
```

which satisfy

```
c = m/f,                                 eq 1
```

the question we have to answer is whether it is valid to compute `c mod q` as

```
(c mod q) = (m mod q)/(f mod q)          eq 2
```

right? Because this would allow us to reduce the calculation of `choose(n,r)` to two series of modular multiplications plus a single division (an easy and efficient algorithm).

Now, `eq 1` can be rewritten as

```
 c*f = m
```

which enables us to apply `mod q` to both sides:

```
 (c mod q)(f mod q) = (m mod q)          eq 3
```

because `mod` is known to commute with products (and sums), which is the very property we will use to compute the series of modular multiplications mentioned above.

And since the tree quantities involved in `eq 3` are integers, we can divide both sides by `(f mod q)` arriving at `eq 2`. My answer is now complete.

**Addendum 2**

I said *My answer is now complete*. Not quite. The problem that still remains happens when `f mod q = 0`, in this case we cannot divide `eq 3` as we did above. This case requires an special treatment and will result in a more complex algorithm.

One idea worth trying is to factor `q`, i.e., `p-1` as a product of primes and consider these primes with their exponents one by one. Take one of them, say `t^e`. We know that `t^e` must divide the factorial `f`. Therefore, it must divide the right hand side of `eq 3` too. So, we have to peek enough factors among `n, n-1, n-2, ..., n-r+1` that are divisible by `t` until we exhaust `e` divisions by `t`. Then we need to replace those factors with their quotient by the corresponding power of `t`. After repeating this procedure for all the primes inside `q=p-1`, we will get `f/q` on the left, and the new list of factors on the right. This will be our new version of `eq 3`. Of course the new `f` (`=f/q`) may be again divisible by `q`. Because of this we have to repeat the same procedure until `f mod q` is no longer `0`. At that point we will be able to divide and get the value of `c mod q`.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem implies that (x^y) mod p = x^(y mod (p-1)) mod p when p does not divide x.

Comment: I think this something i was looking for. Can you prove it? I cannot see how %(p-1) came into picture.